# What's the point of hashing if they've already got a massive rainbow table with all of your users?

Tags: hash, sha256

I am trying to figure out something about this article:

http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/20/facebook-crm-ads/

So, Facebook claims that they respect the privacy of your customer database and that's why they let you upload the hashed email addresses. BUT, what's the point?

It only works by virtue that they've also hashed all the email addresses of their uses to make the hits.

Presumably, the only good this does is that Facebook doesn't know the email addresses of your customers that aren't already Facebook users.

Am I missing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

That's not to protect the email addresses from facebook, but to protect them the rest of the way. If there's a data leak somewhere in the process, chances are that only the hashed addresses will get leaked, making them much harder to misuse.